# How can I replicate functions depending on a variable?

Tags: javascript

Sorry about the vague title – I'm not sure how else I could have described.

Here's the scenario: I have a ton of `if` statements trying to do something like the code below:

```
var wv == today.getDate();

if(wv == 0){
wv0.forEach(function(entry, index)...

if(wv == 1){
wv1.forEach(function(entry, index)...

if(wv == 2){
wv2.forEach(function(entry, index)...
```

The problem is that everything that comes after the `wvX.forEach` is the same for each block of code. Thus I know that it can be condensed but I don't know how to do that.

What I've tried doing is defining a new variable which would give me the `wvX` number depending on the day that it is:

```
var daycode = 'wv' + getDate();
```

Now this gives it to me (so today, on Sunday, it would return `wv0`, but when I try to condense the above like so:

```
if (wv == 0)
daycode.forEach(function(entry, index)...
```

even that doesn't work. I know it would work only for `wv == 0` or Sunday, but it still doesn't work at all. However,

```
if (wv == 0)
wv0.forEach(function(entry, index)...
```

still works even though it is the same thing as the code block above it, as `daycode = wv0` now.

**Edit:** so I just realized something. It's probably because `daycode` is being viewed as a variable. For example, even though `wv0.length` returns `1`, `daycode.length` returns `3`, because the value of `daycode` is `wv0` and the length of `wv0` is three. How else could I do this, then?

Comment: Where do the values in `wv0`, `wv1`, ... come from? Further "a ton of if statements" sounds alarming to me, you should change that (maybe an answer could guide you). What is the code after those `if`s and `for`s dealing with - the results of the loops? What are the loops doing inside?

Comment: you can use just array for `wv0,wv1` and etc functions, and simple get it by index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, which I think is idiomatic, and doesn't resort to eval.

```
var f = function(entry, index){ ... };
var mappings = { 0: wv0, 1: wv1...};
var wv = today.getDate();
mappings[wv].forEach(f);
```

explicitly mapping the date result to the objects you want to iterate over.

Comment: TY! I was killing time with my phone :).

Comment: It should be colon instead of comma in your mappings of 0 to wv0

Comment: This. I'd do it the same way, no ugly eval and no code repeated (not too much anyway).

Comment: Thank you very much! As @ShanShan said, this prevents code from being repeated over and over.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a function inside a variable and pass it to the forEach method.

```
var doThis = function(entry, index {
  // Do something
}

if (wx == 0) { 
  wx3.forEach(doThis)
}
```

This is very unsafe method and make sure you know what are you doing. Use eval method.

```
 eval(fname)(arg1, arg2);
```

Assuming you have this declaration:

```
var arr = [1,4,5,6]
```

You can use eval:

```
eval('arr')
```

It will return `[1,4,5,6]` even you are literally passing a string

So, you can create a function which takes a parameter of a string which associated with the array you are iterating.

```
var iterate = function(arrName) {
  var arr = eval('arrName');
  arr.forEach(......)
```

For the if statement, maybe you can consider using switch statement to simplify the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I don't know how to implement this. I tried doing this: `var daycode = eval("'wv' + getDate()")`, but it still doesn't seem to work. `daycode.length` still returns 3, though `wv0.length` returns 2. Edit: I'm looking at your edit right now.